# Does the Gale-Shapley stable marriage algorithm give at least one person his or her first choice?

Tags: graph-theory

Given $x$ males and $x$ females with their table of priorities, does the Gale-Shapley stable marriage algorithm guarantee that at least one person gets his or her first choice?

It seems like the answer should be no, but all simple examples I can think of don't give this answer no matter how I change the table of priorities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the original article](http://www.econ.ucsb.edu/~tedb/Courses/Ec100C/galeshapley.pdf), that is Example 2 in [*College Admissions and the Stability of Marriage* (Gale and Shapley, 1962)](http://www.econ.ucsb.edu/~tedb/Courses/Ec100C/galeshapley.pdf%20), this may indeed not always be possible to *find* (no matter the algorithm) a stable marriage where anyone gets his or her first choice.

The example the authors give is for $n=4$ men and women, where the ranking matrix is reproduced below.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
& A & B & C & D \\
a & (1,3) & (2,3) & \boxed{(3,2)} & (4,3) \\ 
b & (1,4) & (4,1) & (3,3) & \boxed{(2,2)} \\ 
c & \boxed{(2,2)} & (1,4) & (3,4) & (4,1) \\ 
d & (4,1) & \boxed{(2,2)} & (3,1) & (1,4) \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The only stable marriage is the one highlighted: $(a,C),(b,D),(c,A),(d,B)$. (In particular, the Gale—Shapley algorithm is bound to find this marriage.)